# Fuzzy matching percentage

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

When i query fuzzy matching as follow, elasticsearch still returns only `_score`. But i expect a matching percentage based on the fuzzy algorithm instead. I thought this is a simple configurable thing but i cannot found any of it as it is common to show matching percentage for result of fuzzy match.

How could it be done? Or this is not common "practice" in elasticsearch? But what i found in most user interface do show the matching percentage score for fuzzy match.

```
 "query": { 
        "fuzzy": {
                "name": {
                    "value": "Shahid"
                }
            }
      }
```

Response:

```
"hits" : [{
    "_index" : "users",
    "_type" : "user",
    "_id" : "5sadsadsaddas",
    "_score" : 0.11127616,
    "fuzzyMatchPercentage": 100% // I expect something like this here
    "_source" : {
      "name" : "Shahid",
      "email" : "shahid@codeforgeek.com",
      "city" : "mumbai"
    }
  },
```

Comment: no, it's not possible to do this with out of box elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, this is not how the `fuzzy`-query works in Elasticsearch. By default search results are sorted by descending score, where the score indicates how well a document matches a particular query. The fuzziness aspect is incorporated into the calculation of that score: the more exact/less fuzzy a query matches, the higher the score. You can verify this by requesting a detailed score explanation (in Elasticsearch v7.x the fuzziness aspect is incorporated into the calculation of the boost-factor). Look at the following example:

**1. Indexing two sample documents (one with proper name, one with misspelled name)**

```
POST fuzzy/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"name": "Shahid"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"name": "Shahib"}
```

**2. Searching with the `fuzzy`-query for the name "Shahid"**

```
GET fuzzy/_search
{
  "explain": true, 
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "name": {
        "value": "Shahid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**3. Score and explanation clause for both matching documents**

For the correctly spelled document ("Shahid"):

```
    "_explanation" : {
      "value" : 0.57762265,
      "description" : "sum of:",
      "details" : [
        {
          "value" : 0.57762265,
          "description" : "weight(name:shahid in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
          "details" : [
            {
              "value" : 0.57762265,
              "description" : "score(freq=1.0), product of:",
              "details" : [
                {
                  "value" : 1.8333334,
                  "description" : "boost",
                  "details" : [ ]
                },
                {
                  "value" : 0.6931472,
                  "description" : "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                  "details" : [
                    {
                      "value" : 1,
                      "description" : "n, number of documents containing term",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 2,
                      "description" : "N, total number of documents with field",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "value" : 0.45454544,
                  "description" : "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                  "details" : [
                    {
                      "value" : 1.0,
                      "description" : "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 1.2,
                      "description" : "k1, term saturation parameter",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 0.75,
                      "description" : "b, length normalization parameter",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 1.0,
                      "description" : "dl, length of field",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 1.0,
                      "description" : "avgdl, average length of field",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

For the wrongly spelled document ("Shahib"):

```
    "_explanation" : {
      "value" : 0.46209806,
      "description" : "sum of:",
      "details" : [
        {
          "value" : 0.46209806,
          "description" : "weight(name:shahib in 1) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
          "details" : [
            {
              "value" : 0.46209806,
              "description" : "score(freq=1.0), product of:",
              "details" : [
                {
                  "value" : 1.4666666,
                  "description" : "boost",
                  "details" : [ ]
                },
                {
                  "value" : 0.6931472,
                  "description" : "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                  "details" : [
                    {
                      "value" : 1,
                      "description" : "n, number of documents containing term",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 2,
                      "description" : "N, total number of documents with field",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "value" : 0.45454544,
                  "description" : "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                  "details" : [
                    {
                      "value" : 1.0,
                      "description" : "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 1.2,
                      "description" : "k1, term saturation parameter",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 0.75,
                      "description" : "b, length normalization parameter",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 1.0,
                      "description" : "dl, length of field",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 1.0,
                      "description" : "avgdl, average length of field",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

**4. Conclusion**
Unfortunately there is no detailed explanation of the boost-factor (Elasticsearch issue), but from the example it can be seen, that this is the only difference with respect to scoring of the two documents:

- Shahid: _score: 0.57762265 / boost: 1.8333334
- Shahib: _score: 0.46209806 / boost: 1.4666666

Comment: @c448548 (https://stackoverflow.com/users/12008586/c448548) please indicate whether the answer solved your "problem"